# Unexplained Logon Script Error Partially Resolved by msiexec

Tags: powershell, vbscript, outlook, citrix, windows-installer

**Update**

This is only happening when the logon script is set to a non-VBS file in AD. If I set the calling file to a VBS script this message does not appear. This seems to be the exact opposite of what should be happening.

---

I am in the process of converting a VBS logon script to Powershell, and after rewriting most of the logic I am seeing this error when Outlook is opened (this is in a citrix session):

> Microsoft Outlook cannot provide form scripting support.
>
> This feature is not available. For more information, contact your system administrator.

After searching around I found that running this at the beginning of the script seems to resolve it:

`Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/i {90150000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE} ADDLOCAL=OutlookVBScript /qn" -Wait`

But this only works intermittently (could be a timing issue), and causes the logon script to take longer than usual.

Can anyone please explain what this is actually doing, and why it might resolve the issue I am seeing??

The old script (VBS) was a simple VBS file, where the new Powershell script is called from a .BAT like so:

`START "" Powershell.exe -NoLogo -noninteractive -executionpolicy remotesigned -WindowStyle Hidden -File \\DC1\NETLOGON\PSSubs\mainlogon.ps1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the MSIEXEC method was not reliable enough, I used the other fix, which is to go on to the server and remove this registry key value:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT:\Installer\Features\00005109110000000000000000F01FEC\OutlookVBScript`

Where the string after 'Features' is dependant on the version of office.

[Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/924221)

[TechNet Social](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1c6c8973-17d0-40ec-9c2a-d7835d2d77e5/outlook-2010-cannot-provide-form-scripting-support?forum=outlook)

I have no idea what this registry value does, but I haven't had any detrimental effects yet. Will post here if I notice anything.